# Lighttpd doesn't read mime-type from files without an extension

Tags: web-server, configuration, lighttpd, mime-type

I have a folder with images that I need to be lightweight hosted. So I decided to go for lighttpd.

So I read that I had to add the following option in the config file:

```
mimetype.use-xattr = "enable"
```

It didn't work, when loading an image it was sended with an `application/octet-stream` file type header, and the browser would download it.

I read that the `--use-attr` was a flag when compiling, so I thought that maybe it was compiled without it (the build was from the Ubuntu repo) ([the documentation](http://www.installationwiki.org/Installing_Lighttpd) says that the flag is actually `--use-atttr` but I think is a typo error since it says that option is unrecognized when I run `configure`).

So I downloaded the source and compiled and installed it with that flag:

```
configure --with-attr
make
make install
```

And here are the lighttpd features and version:

```
/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -V
lighttpd/1.4.30-devel-2805 - a light and fast webserver
Build-Date: Oct  6 2011 10:39:46

Event Handlers:

        + select (generic)
        + poll (Unix)
        - rt-signals (Linux 2.4+)
        + epoll (Linux 2.6)
        - /dev/poll (Solaris)
        - eventports (Solaris)
        - kqueue (FreeBSD)
        - libev (generic)

Network handler:

        + sendfile

Features:

        + IPv6 support
        + zlib support
        + bzip2 support
        + crypt support
        - SSL Support
        + PCRE support
        - mySQL support
        - LDAP support
        - memcached support
        - FAM support
        - LUA support
        - xml support
        - SQLite support
        - GDBM support
```

Comment: Are the Content-Type attributes in place on your image files?

Comment: Does your lighthttpd.conf have correct values for mimetype.assign ? like this http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wp-content/uploads/2006/07/lighttpd.conf.txt (that is assuming the question being about viewing and NOT downloading images in lighthttpd)

Comment: @ShaneMadden `file -b --mime-type` returns the correct value, so I guess the attributes are fine.

@user The files don't have extensions so `mimetype.assign` would be rather useless, that's why I want Lighttpd to read the mime type from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the extended attribute is in place with `attr -g Content-Type`, not `file`.  Are you on a filesystem that supports XFS extended attributes, and are they in place?

`mimetype.use-xattr` is looking for extended attributes, while `file` is identifying the file via magic numbers.

Comment: It throws an error saying `attr_get: No such file or directory` and then it says it could not read the attribute from the file.
So I guess my filesystem doesn't support XFS?

Comment: @Zequez Did you give it the file location?  Try `attr -l /path/to/file` - if there's no attributes, it should give a blank response.  If that's the case, try setting a `Content-Type` attribute and see if it'll go; `attr -s Content-Type -V image/jpeg /path/to/file`

Comment: yes, I gave the file name. When I tried `attr -s Content-Type -V image/jpeg /path/to/file` it threw `attr_set: Operation not supported`

Comment: @Zequez Seems that extended attributes are not supported, then.

Comment: well, thanks ^^. It seems that I'm going to have to find another way :B